# load files in background without blocking prompt

Tags: octave

I am using Octave 4.0 (on windows (with gui)).
Is there any way or trick to load large data files in background?
So that octave can be used in the mean time?

Comment: What task(s) are you trying to perform and why must they be done while the data is loading? While the [parallel package](http://wiki.octave.org/Parallel_package) can be used to parallelize specific functions, Octave is still executing serially so it's blocked until the operation is complete.

Comment: its more for convenience. I often end up loading data files and i am forced to wait while i could do other things with data that is already present. Also some scripts would gain benefit from this

Comment: I'm not sure I see any functional difference between that and just loading/processing your data in chunks.

Comment: @excaza maybe you see no difference. for me there is one.

Comment: If your data is in ascii format, then loading it in another session running in parallel, and saving it to hdf5, might make it much quicker to open from the main session.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch ok, good luck